# ASPNET Identity user return the old record when get user by id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I had a problem when using identity user. After call the `Update(user)`, the record in database has been changed. The problem occur when I call `Method(string userId)` again, contain `FindById(userId)`. The `FindById(userId)` returns a user with all record still remain as the first although I has updated it before.

I implement user table:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public int MyProperty { set; get; } 
}
```

The user manager class:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationUserManager
{
  public Task MethodAsync(string userId)
  {
    // Find user 
    // return object before change (MyProperty not equal 1)
    ApplicationUser user = await base.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    user.MyProperty = 1; 
    await base.UpdateAsync()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen only when you are updating the *current logged-in user*'s properties?  If so, try to re-sign in again:

```
SignInManager.SignIn(user, false, false)
```

The user object can be gotten from the `UserManager.FindById` method.